# Initialize an OpenCV Mat with pixel data in RGBA channel order

Tags: c++, opencv

Hel lo,

I am writing an effect plug-in for Adobe After Effects in C++, and I need to create a `cv::Mat` using pixel data that's already in memory. However, when I initialize it using:

```
cv::Mat in_frame_mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, input->data);
```

(input->data is a pointer to the first byte), the output is all blue.
I think this is because AE stores pixel data RGBA or ARGB while OpenCV assumes BGRA or ABGR (not sure which).

I know that I could iterate through every pixel and create a new space in memory to store a BGRA representation of the image, then initialize a `cv::Mat` with *that*, but this is really performance constrained and I don't want to add unnecessary compute time.

Is there a way to create a `cv::Mat` using existing pixel data that is stored RGBA?

Thanks!

Comment: ok then, `cvtColor` -- your processing likely doesn't care, *you* care when you look at the picture with `imshow`/`imread`. just do your thing and keep channel order. it won't be blue in AE.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I thought of that, but the processing that I want to do on the mat requires it to have a correct colorspace. I ended up writing my own function that converts the colorspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV assumes the channel order is **BGR** (or **BGRA**).

You can use [`cv::cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to change your input to BGRA.
The 3rd parameter `code` should be one of the values from [`cv::ColorConversionCodes`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html), e.g.: `cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA` (seems to be what you need).

---

**Update:**

Following the OP's comment below that his input is actually ARGB (not RGBA):
ARGB to BGRA is not supported by `cv::cvtColor`.
But you can use [`cv:mixChannels`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) to do any arbitrary reordering of the channels (the `fromTo` parameter specifies the reordering).

See below how to use it to convert **ARGB** to **BGRA**:

```
#include <vector>
cv::Mat argb; // initialized from your input data
cv::Mat bgra(argb.size(), argb.type());
std::vector<int> fromTo{ 0,3, 1,2, 2,1, 3,0 };  // ARGB->BGRA: 0->3, 1->2, 2->1, 3->0
cv::mixChannels(argb, bgra, fromTo);
```

If your OpenCV version does not support this flavor of `cv::mixChannels` (with `std::vector` etc.), you can try:

```
cv::Mat argb; // initialized from your input data
cv::Mat bgra(argb.size(), argb.type());
int fromTo[] = { 0,3, 1,2, 2,1, 3,0 };    // ARGB->BGRA: 0->3, 1->2, 2->1, 3->0
cv::mixChannels(&argb, 1, &bgra, 1, fromTo, 4);
```

---

**Update 2:**

In order to convert **ARGB** to **BGR** (i.e. without the alpha channel), you can use `cv::mixChannels` in the following way:

```
#include <vector>
cv::Mat argb; // initialized from your input data
cv::Mat bgr(argb.size(), CV_8UC3); // NOTE: the type is CV_8UC3, not argb.type()
std::vector<int> fromTo{ 1,2, 2,1, 3,0 };  // ARGB->BGR: 1->2, 2->1, 3->0
cv::mixChannels(argb, bgr, fromTo);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it turns out that After Effects does in fact use ARGB, so it doesn't seem like there's a way to convert that to BGR using cv::cvtColor. I'll probably end up writing a function to do it manually.

Comment: @jonahclarsen - turned out you don't have to do it manually - see the update to my answer.

Comment: Awesome - that worked. Thanks so much! That does it in 19 less lines of code. Unfortunately though, it's a little slower than doing it manually. I think it's because I don't need transparency data and so when I copy it manually I don't have to touch the alpha channel (ARGB->BGR). I tried modifying this solution to not touch the alpha channel (by interpreting the input as CV_8UC3 instead of CV_8UC4 and by removing the ", 3, 0") but I couldn't get it to work, it either created corrupted images or crashed.

Comment: @jonahclarsen - I added a 2nd update to my answer, with the way to use `cv::mixChannels` for converting ARGB -> BGR.